# How do I check if a http response is plaintext or not in javascript?

Tags: javascript, http, text

I'm using `fetch("http://example.org/" + path)` to get a webpage. If the response is plaintext, like HTML, CSS or JS, I want to perform an operation on the plaintext (first, .text() to turn the body into a string, and then .replace()). But if the response is not plaintext, like JPG or MP4, I don't want to do that because, as the warning says, .text() will corrupt it. "Called .text() on an HTTP body which does not appear to be text. The body's Content-Type is "image/jpeg". The result will probably be corrupted. Consider checking the Content-Type header before interpreting entities as text.".

I could check on mimetype, or take the path variable to check the file extension, but then I'll have to check what kind of files are requested. That's cumbersome but the biggest problem is that it isn't future-proof, I'll have to add the mimetype or file extension every time a new kind of file is added. It seems stupid to do this since, looking at the warning, javascript already knows the jpeg isn't plaintext.

Comment: Use the response header content-type

Comment: All you've got when the first `fetch()` promise resolves is the header. You can't at that time look at the content because it hasn't arrived. You can use `.blob()` instead of `.text()` and then perform content tests on that, which would be fairly involved in general.

Comment: @Daniel I was actually looking for a more generic solution than manually checking a list of plaintext content types that I would have to update every time a file is added with a content type that isn't in the list yet - see the second paragraph of my post

Comment: @Pointy - Or [`arrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/arrayBuffer)

Comment: Sounds like an x-y problem. What is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Kaassoufflé - A fair amount can be done just with the first part, `text/` vs. `image/` vs. `audio/` ... If not with the content type then you'll have to do analysis on the data you get back, which means first fetching it with a binary-friendly method (like `blob` or `arrayBuffer`) and then doing your analysis.

Comment: @Mark I'm creating a cloudflare worker that proxies a website. I want to find-and-replace all occurrences of the original URL in the HTML, CSS, JS, etc so the content that the HTML loads also goes through the proxy. But not in non-text files because 1. they get corrupted and 2. they don't load in additional content

Comment: *javascript already knows the jpeg isn't plaintext* - it looks at the mime type

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.